# Splittable and non-splittable flows in the network flow problem

Tags: linear-programming, graph-theory

I am working on a multi-commodity flow problem where for a graph $G=(V, E)$, some flows are permitted to be split and some flows should strictly follow one path. I have formulated this problem as follows.

**Problem Formulation**

$$ \min \sum_{(i,j) \in E} \sum_{f \in F} c_{ij}^fx^f_{ij}$$

$$ \sum_{j \in V}x^f_{ij} - \sum_{j \in V}x_{ji}^f = \begin{cases}
d_f  &, & i = s_f \\
-d_f&, & i = t_f\\
0 &,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$
$$ x_{ij}^f \ge \begin{cases}
0 & , & f \in S\\
d_f & , & f \in NS\\
\end{cases} \quad \forall (i, j) \in E$$
$$ \sum_{i,j \in E} x_{ij}^f \le u_{ij}$$

Where $d_f$ is the demand for flow $f$. $S$ is the set of flows that are permitted to be split, and $NS$ is the set of non-splittable flows. $u_{ij}$ is the capacity of edge $(i, j)$.

I am a novice in linear programming. On paper, using two simple graphs, this formulation seems to work fine.

I would appreciate it if someone could point out if there is any problem with this formulation.

Comment: I don't quite know what exactly you are looking for. It's a legitimate linear programming problem alright and as long as the costs $c_{ij}^f$ are positive, it's also guaranteed to have a solution because your solution variables are required to be positive. Are you asking whether the *model* is reasonable? We can't tell you anything about that because we don't know in detail what you are trying to model.

Comment: Thank you @WolfgangBangerth. I wasn't sure if my problem formulation is a legitimate LP. Also, to force the non-splittable flows to follow one path only, without turning this problem into a MIP, I added this constraint: $$ x_{ij}^f \ge \begin{cases}
0 & , & f \in S\\
d_f & , & f \in NS\\
\end{cases} \quad \forall (i, j) \in E$$
So, I wanted to know whether this constraint does what I expect it to do or not.

Comment: We don't know -- we don't know what all of your variables are supposed to mean. Your problem sounds like it is bounded from below, but I can't say whether your constraints allow for at least one feasible point.

Comment: On another forum, someone commented: "your program does not allow $x^f_{ij}$ to be 0 if $f \in NS$, which seems incorrect. You have to use binary variables for $f \in NS$ and $(i,j) \in E$ to ensure that $x^f_{ij}$ is either $0$ or $d_f$ ". 

It is not clear to me why the program should allow $x^f_{ij}$ to be 0 if $f \in NS$. Sadly he didn't elaborate on this point. Can someone please tell me what he meant by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current model you are forcing your non splittable flows to be equal to your demand on all arcs ( $ x^f_{ij} \geq d_f, \forall f \in NS$). Unless there is a single path from your source to your target this is going to make your problem infeasible, as the flow conservation constraints are going to conflict with this. I am afraid that for non splittable flows you do not have many alternatives to model whether or not a flow goes through an arc using a binary variable, effectively turning your problem into a MIP.

**Edit 1:** To model the problem as a MIP, for the non-splittable flows you need to replace the $x_{ij}^f$ linear variables by $y_{ij}^f$ binary variables representing if the complete flow goes through arc $ij$ or not. You should then rewrite your constraint and objective function by replacing for non splittable flows $x_{ij}^f$ by $y_{ij}^fd_f$

Comment: Thank you for your answer Renaud. To check If I understood you correctly, you mean I don't have much choice in formulating this problem, and I should formulate it as a MIP? If yes, would you please tell me how can I formulate it as a MIP because I am totally clueless.

Comment: Finally, I was able to implement this formulation in CPLEX, and then tested it on two simple graphs ([1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qv5k.png, and [2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0uEo.png). However, as @renaud-m expected, CPLEX cannot find any feasible solution (due to either link capacity or flow conservation constraints violation, for different scenarios). I would appreciate it, if someone could explain to me how I can resolve the problem with the formulation, in a simple language (English is not my first language).

Comment: Renaud, thank you for guiding me through this.  I read a little bit on MIPs and as you suggested, I tried to reformulate the problem as MIP. I will be grateful if you or anyone else could point out the problems with this new formulation.

Comment: @Corey your formulation looks good. The notation is a bit odd as you are summing y variables even for splittable flows while those variables do not exist for such flows, but otherwise it looks correct to me.

Comment: can you suggest a way to make the notations less odd?

Comment: @Corey well one sum over the splittable flows and another one over the non splittable flows

Comment: Is it less odd now Renaud?

Comment: @Corey indeed better :-) let me know if the model works as expected...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84501/discussion-between-corey-and-renaud-m).